# Ionic image upload with PHP server

Tags: php, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, image-uploading

I have a problem with my ionic app.
I want to upload an image to my php server when i click on a button but it seems that i am doing something wrong...

**Communication.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic3 Server Send Test
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
<button ion-button (click)="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
</ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**Communication.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';

@Component({
    selector: 'communication',
    templateUrl: 'communication.html'
})


export class CommunicationPage {
  imageURI:any;
imageFileName:any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  private transfer: FileTransfer) {}

  uploadFile() {

  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  let options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'ionicfile',
    fileName: 'ionicfile',
    chunkedMode: false,
    headers: {}
  }

  fileTransfer.upload('C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/Recognize/src/pages/communication/test.png', 'http://someserver', options)
    .then((data) => {
    console.log(data+" Uploaded Successfully");
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
}
```

I have this error when i click on the upload button :

```
FileTransferError {code: 1, source:"C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/Recognize/src/pages/communication/test.png", target: "http://someserver", http_status: null, body: null, …}
```

I know there is a problem with the url of the "test.png" file because of code 1 error.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add image targetPath in `fileTransfer.upload()` like this,

```
var targetPath = this.file.dataDirectory + imgName;

fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, 'http://someserver', options)
    .then((data) => {
    console.log(data+" Uploaded Successfully");
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: var targetPath = this.file.dataDirectory + 'test.png';                                          i have this error now :                                                                                        Property 'file' does not exist on type 'CommunicationPage'.

Comment: you need to add ionic native File plugin to get default path of the device.

Comment: I did and import : import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';                            but still same error...

Comment: import file plugin like this import { File } from '@ionic-native/file'; and put in like this constructor(private file: File) { } and also import file plugin in app.module file

Comment: ok error is gone but now there is an error on button click : FileTransferError {code: 1, source: "filesystem:file:///persistent/test.png", target: "http:// someserver", http_status: null, body: null, …}

Answer (score 0):

Hey Nathan the problem you are having is because of the URL of file, here you are giving the url only test.png.

Rather than you should use [FileChooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/) plugin for cordova which gives the absolute URL of the file.

```
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';

constructor(private fileChooser: FileChooser) { }
function() {
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  let options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'ionicfile',
    fileName: 'ionicfile',
    chunkedMode: false,
    headers: {}
  }


this.fileChooser.open()
  .then(uri => {
      fileTransfer.upload(uri, 'http://someserver', options)
    .then((data) => {
    console.log(data+" Uploaded Successfully");
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

}
```

Comment down if you want some more help.

Comment: I don't want to choose the file manually. I just want to upload my image "test.png" on the server when i click on the button.

Comment: can you tell me how where is the image in your project, you need to put the absolute path of the image eg => D:/folder/project_folder/src/assets/imgs/test.png

Comment: My image is in the communication folder. There is the same error, even if i put the absolute path : C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/Recognize/src/pages/communication/test.png

Comment: Put that image in assets folder in imgs sub folder and use that path, you will get result. @na

Comment: Same error... FileTransferError {code: 1, source: "C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/Recognize/src/assets/imgs/test.png", target: "http:// someserver", http_status: null, body: null, …}